# 'Not Like' Not Working

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-like

I'm trying to return results for service orders from a table that contains Document No. and  Unit of Measure as the column header.  The Unit of Measure column contains terms 'EACH', 'CHARGE' and 'HOUR'. I do not want to return any results for any Document No. whose Unit of Measure data contains the term 'Hour' I've tried Unit of Measure Not Like = 'Hour' in my Where clause but I still keep getting results with Hour.  See two service orders from table I am trying to query.  I dont want to return "Document No. svo-13352.

[image]

```
select [Document No.]
from   [Service Line]
where  [Unit of Measure] not like 'HOUR'
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what you're doing, so it's pretty difficult to tell you what you're doing wrong. Please [edit] to provide the query you're using that isn't working for you.

Comment: Yes, provide full query and also what type of database you are using.

Comment: You may need to match case if dealing with Oracle -- 'HOUR'

Comment: You're probably getting down votes because you didn't post your query.  It looks like 'Unit of Measure' is all upper case.  Is your SQL variant case sensitive?  If so, NOT Like = 'Hour' is working as it should.  Not sure why you are using LIKE.  Why not just Unit of Measure <> 'HOUR'?

Comment: This still returns the lines that read each and charge.  I'm wanting to return Document No.(Service Orders) that do not have any labor(Hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select distinct ([Document No.]) from [Service Line]
where [Document No.] not in
(
   select distinct( [Document No.] ) from [Service Line] where [Unit of Measure] like 'HOUR'
)
```

Comment: Nailed it.  Thanks so much.